# adjusting images sizes to different iPhone screen sizes in Xcode

Tags: ios, swift

I constructed the storyboard in the size class "compact width and regular height." when i run it in the iPhone 6 simulator, it looks fine and exactly as it does on the screen. but when i run the app on the iPhone 5 simulator, the images run off the screen. basically all the elements kept their exact size and did not scale down to the smaller screen size of the iPhone 5.

likewise, when run it in the iPhone 6plus simulator there is a lot of extra white space.

how can I fix this? is there an easy fix or do I have to remake all of the storyboards that I've done?

Comment: You have to use aspect fill

Comment: Aspect fill does not work. i have labeled all buttons on the screen with aspect fill in the "view" area, and it still isn't working.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are doing it with the IB you need to set aspect fill. Sometimes constraints will complain if you do this so only set ones that won't hurt you.